# C++ friend template function: Function definition not found

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2019, friend

While trying to wrap my head around C++ templates I have run into a compiler warning I do not understand. In below `vec.h` Visual Studio 2019 will put a green squiggle under `operator<<<T>` in `class vec` with the warning "Function definition for `operator<<<T>` not found.

The code otherwise compiles and runs fine. In particular I do not understand how this case differs from `operator+` which does not generate a warning.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class vec;

template<typename T>
vec<T> operator+(const vec<T>& a, const vec<T>& b);

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec<T>& v);

template<typename T>
class vec {
public:
    vec(T xx = 0, T yy = 0) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
    friend vec<T> operator+<T>(const vec<T>& a, const vec<T>& b);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<<T>(std::ostream& os, const vec<T>& v);
private:
    T x, y;
};
```

In `vec.cpp` I put the function templates for the friend functions and some explicit instantiations.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "vec.h"

template<typename T>
vec<T> operator+(const vec<T>& a, const vec<T>& b) {
    return vec<T>(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

template vec<int> operator+(const vec<int>& a, const vec<int>& b);
template vec<float> operator+(const vec<float>& a, const vec<float>& b);

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec<T>& v) {
    return os << "<" << v.x << "," << v.y << ">";
}

template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec<int>& v);
template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec<float>& v);
```

Comment: Try adding a space between `<<` and `<T>`? Note this isn't a compiler warning, it's an intellisense warning which aren't always 100% accurate

Comment: Try compiling, do you get an actual error?

Comment: Adding a space between << and <T> does not help. Renaming operator<< to operator>> does make the squiggle disappear. So this may just be a parsing issue with IntelliSense?

Comment: Most likely yeah, incorrect intellisense warnings are not an uncommon thing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the shown code. The visual studio intellisense warning is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an incorrect warning by Visual Studio IntelliSense. The code is well-formed and is compiled successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively the code below

```
// vec.h
template<typename T>
class vec;

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec<T>& v);

template<typename T>
struct vec {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& os, const vec<T>& v);
};
```

could be written as (without `<<<T>`)

```
// vec.h
template<typename T>
struct vec {
    template<typename T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vec<T>& v);
};
```

It is just a matter of personal preference.